# Testing a set of links using Selenium & Cucumber JVM-Java

Tags: java, loops, selenium, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

I've got a page I'm developing that consists of a series of categories, subcategories, and links. Basically there are several hundred links that are listed in a hierarchy under the main categories. The main categories contain between 1 and 4 levels of depth (i.e. some main categories contain direct links while others contain 3 levels of subcategories that lead to direct links).

The page is built using Angular, so clicking subcategory links will essentially update the model to load the appropriate data, while clicking direct links will open the URL in an external window. There is a breadcrumb for moving back and forth between levels. When a category is clicked, the user is taken to a new view where all of the subcategories under it are displayed, including any direct links at that level. From here, the user can look through any number of levels until the desired direct link is found. The point being, the levels of the hierarchy are not consistent.

That part is not so important, because I've already developed a class for testing the links at all levels using Selenium by looping through the levels to open each direct link URL found. But I wanted to give an overview of what how the page is set up. It's not simply one list of links to test - rather, it's a multi-level hierarchy that leads to links to external sites.

As I mentioned, the Selenium  test works fine. The Java class reads the expected hierarchy and URLs from an Excel sheet, navigates through the page until it finds a direct link, opens it, and verifies the page loaded contains the expected URL. In the same Excel sheet, the program writes a value of PASS or FAIL based on the result of the test.

The issue I'm having is converting my existing Selenium example into Cucumber step definitions. The biggest problem I see is the reliance on nested loops to check the levels of the hierarchy of all of the direct links. I don't quite understand how to use loops in Cucumber. The more I read about it, the more it seems like this is not the right application of Cucumber functionality. Am I wrong to try to use Cucumber for testing a link-testing runner like this? I just can't seem to map a reasonable number of features and step definitions. The way I understand Cucumber so far is that you write a finite number of features that are mapped to the methods using the @Given, @When, @Then, etc. annotations (i.e. each test case is mapped out individually). You'd have to know exactly the number of test cases to run, whereas the Selenium example I have dynamically determines how many cases to run based on the links read from the Excel sheet .In other words, it seems like it is not practical to write a feature for each link hierarchy. I started with simple features like below, and I've hit a wall because I don't see how I can loop through and run these step for each link:

```
Feature: Click Final Link

Scenario: Successfully click final link
  When User Clicks on Final Link
  Then Load Link
```

---

```
@When("^User Clicks on Final Link$")
public void User_Clicks_on_Final_Link() throws Throwable {
    // Express the Regexp above with the code you wish you had
    throw new PendingException();
}
```

---

```
Feature: Click Category

Scenario: Successfully click category link
  When User Clicks on Category Link
  Then Load Subcategory Links
```

---

```
@When("^User Clicks on Category Link$")
public void User_Clicks_on_Category_Link() throws Throwable {
    // Express the Regexp above with the code you wish you had
    throw new PendingException();
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you need to test? that you don't have broken links (404's)?

Comment: @lauda Exactly. That there are no 404s and that the URL of the page that opens from a given link (selected by its xpath) is the expected URL found in the Excel sheet.

Answer (score 1):

I think that cucumber is not made for this, you should test some specifications not that the page is opened or not.
You would not want to have a failed test for almost each broken link.

Some of the options are:

1. use some known tool (even online if you don't have any security restrictions) that checks all your website for broken links
2. find a library to use with cucumber that automatically crawl all the pages and checks for broken links. This option you can integrate it in a step.
3. write/search for a custom script that crawls all the pages and checks for all links and use it in your scenario

I think is a better approach to use a script to crawl and check the links than keeping the links hard-coded in a file.

I suggest integrating this functionality in a scenario only in the case that you have an automated suite and for each run you want to do this check also.